# weighted average in collaborative filtering

Tags: recommender-system, aggregation

I studied on collaborative filtering recently and found that for ratings at last most methods applied were weighted average, no matter what they had proposed, similarity, time, etc.

Thus I am wondering whether there is another way to forecast the ratings. Well, I could only come up with weighted average listed above and majority vote since this is kind of an aggregation problem.

Are there any other alternative methods?

Edit: I was trying to ask for another way to aggregate ratings from others or history or whatever rather than weighted average, which just stroke me from nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what do you try to ask. Do you want to know another method of weighting the rating score in collaborative filtering(CF)? Or do you just want to know other techniques of rating?

The CF method is commonly used in recommender systems of the matching stage, in which new contents or products are retrieved. These contents or products are then filtered by a rough ranker (pre-ranking) to reduce the number of items from thousands to hundreds. After that, a ranking model to rank these items to produce the final rating score. However, that's not the final stage of the recommender system, a re-ranking stage, it is commonly adopted in many companies, to re-weight the score of the ranking stage, based on the business goals, like click, duration, ROI, etc. Business goal, it's the internal driven power of weighting the rating score.

The weighted average method is the most profound way to re-weight the rating score, It's easy and explainable for the result. Yet, there are other ways to re-weighted the rating score.

1. Sample the dataset based on your business goal. The model is not fit the goal/target, it fits on the data distribution. If you enter the field of recommendation, you will find this is the most effective way of boosting your model performance;
2. Weighted on the loss, it's quite similar to weight on the rating, however, this happens inside the model, and it adds more punishment to the model's false prediction;
3. Weighted on the record, it's similar to sampling the dataset, however, this adds weights to the records, and it will speed up the training process because it didn't increase the number of the training dataset.
4. Using the attention layer. Change the model structure, adding learnable weights to your loss function (in case you are training a multi-task model, you will need to balance the predictive power of these tasks), concatenate function, pooling layer, etc. Let the model learn weights automatically for you.

That is all I know about ways of weighting the rating score, there might be other techniques that are not included in this draft, please comment below and share with us.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Well, this is too much for now. I was trying to ask for another way to aggregate ratings from others or history or whatever rather than weighted average, which just stroke me from nowhere, immature or probably wrong.

Comment: Oh, I see. However, you could state your question clearly above, add details might help others understand your question@user567445.

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.